# How to see page numbers with IText and the landscape format

Tags: itext

I need to add page numbers to a pdf. I following this guide:
http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104

All work if i set:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4,36, 36, 54, 36);
```

But i need a landscape:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER.rotate(),36, 36, 54, 36);
```

With this format i can't see page numbers. How can i resolve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In that sample you position the header with

```
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, writer.getDirectContent());
```

The `34, 803` is the position. As a landscape page is not as high, you will have to decrease the `803`.

Most likely you will simultaneously want to increase the `527` in

```
table.setTotalWidth(527);
```

as the landscape page is wider.

Comment: That's great. Please accept the answer (you can do that on the left side of the answer).